# Send variable between PCs over the internet using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking

I have two computers with internet connection. They both have public IPs and they are NATed. What I want is to send a variable from PC A to PC B and close the connection.

I have thought of two approaches for this:

1) Using sockets. PC B will have listen to a connection from PC A. Then, when the variable will be sent, the connection will be closed. The problem is that, the sockets will not communicate, because I have to forward the traffic from my public IP to PC B.

2) An out of the box idea, is to have the variable broadcasted online somewhere. I mean making a public IP hold the variable in HTML and then the PC would GET the IP from and get the variable. The problem is, how do I make that variable accessible over the internet?

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: does the PCs A & B have the public IP on the system? or do they have a private IP address which is NAT'ed to a public IP from the router?

Comment: They do not have public IPs. Only the router does have a public IP. The PCs are NATed

Comment: You may want to use a VPN for that, try OpenVPN it's pretty easy to setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured a solution out. I make a dummy server using `flask` and I hosted it at `pythonanywhere.com` for free. The variables are posted to the server from PC A and then, PC B uses the `GET` method to get them locally.